# Downloading files with Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, header, controller, action, download

I'm a newbie to Zend Framework and I have such problem. On my web page I have the demos of products to be downloaded by users. When they want to download them, they have to fill the form (name, company, e-mail, contact phone) and then click Submit to start downloading. I would like them to be redirected to the product page. Here is my showFormAction code in controller:

```
    if ($this->_request->isPost())
    {
        if (!$form->isValid($this->_request->getPost()))  
        {   
            //shows messages and the form again             
        }               
        else 
        { 

            $file = $this->findYoungestFile('/demo/'.$product.'/');
            $this->sendFileToClient($file);
            $this->_redirect('/products/'.$product);
            //sending mail
            $infoMail = new InfoMail($this->_request->getPost(), 'download', $product);
            $this->sendInfoMails($infoMail);                
        }   
    } 
    else
        //show form
```

And here is sendFileToClient function

```
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

        readfile($file);
```

The redirection doesn't work. I suppose there is a problem with headers sent to the browser, but I don't know how to solve it. Could anyone help me, please?

Thanks & regards,
Malgorzata

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What is the output you get?

Comment: It sends the file to browser, sends the e-mail, but doesn't redirect, stays on the same page.

Comment: Oh. The redirect is a header as well. Takes no effect after you have already sent the file download header :).

Comment: OK, is there any possibility to solve this? I wondered about making the download action in the blank tab, but I don't know how to do it exactly

Comment: I know of no simple way, but you could try using an iframe (perhaps with display:none) and just loading the file download headers inside it. It's hacky, but might be worth a try :).

Comment: OK, I will try to do it this way. Thank you for your help:)

Answer (score 1):

By the time you're trying to redirect user to another page the HTTP-headers had already sent. In other words you cannot supply a file and do a redirect at the same time. Well, at least the way you're trying to do this.

Comment: OK, bu is there any solution? I wonder, if I can make two actions for this download. One will be responsible for sending the file, the other for redirecting.

Comment: You could redirect to the page needed first and then through let's say <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="15;URL=http://www.domain.com/path/to/file"> or js, supply a file.

Comment: I would rather like to make file downloading via zend.

Comment: Of course, Js/meta tags will only do a redirect to a file itself.

Comment: OK, I will try to do it with iframe. Thank you for your help:)